# Creating form arrays with Laravel 4

Tags: arrays, forms, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 4 I can create text inputs with code like:

```
{{ Form::text('title', '', ['placeholder' => 'Ex. title', 'id' => 'title']) }}
```

This is very useful, because if other fields of my form fail validation, I can just do...

```
return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::all());
```

And when the form is shown again, the field `title` will conserve the value that was submitted before.

Good stuff.

Now here is my problem: What about **input arrays**?

I added the following input fields to my form:

```
<input type="text" name="option[]" />
<input type="text" name="option[]" />
<input type="text" name="option[]" />
<input type="text" name="option[]" />
```

And I submitted the form, knowing that would fail, to see if when the form appears again, the values on these fields still remained. Instead Laravel threw an exception.

> ErrorException
>
> htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

**Even if I have just 1 option**, it still gives me the same error:

```
{{ Form::text('option[]') }}
```

Now, I know that I could handle the filling of the array option manually, maybe like this:

```
$options = Input::get('option');
return Redirect::back()
    ->withErrors($validator)
    ->withInput(Input::except('option'))
    ->with('options', $options);
```

and then just looping through the $option array on the blade template.

Yes, that would probably work. But that is kinda hacky, and it still misses the powerful workflow of Laravel to autofill fields after failed submission, like I did back with `title`. So my question is:

Is there any built-in way in Laravel 4 to handle Input Arrays under these situations?

Comment: `I have tried to do this, and I got this error` what did you try exactly? I can see the expected output but how did you try and implement it?

Comment: Just as written. I added a collection of text fields that were arrays "option[]", and when reacting to the "return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput(Input::all());", the fields not only did not get populated, but Laravel threw an error. Im not sure what you are missing. I put all the relevant code there...

Answer (score 0):

If you add an index to each input like:

`{{ Form::text('option[1]') }} {{ Form::text('option[2]') }}` it will work.

You can see how this works in `vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Html\FormBuilder.php` in the function that creates the input

Comment: Yeah. I know I can put whatever I want on the name. But it will still give me an error, when I return an error.